# Curved layout divider

Tags: android, android-layout, divider

I'm trying to create a curved layout divider similar to this one
[image]

I managed to made a similar divider, but I can't figure out how can I make it curved.
Is that possible?

Comment: Please elaborate where you intend to use it and what for. Also you should provide your previous efforts to solve this problem

Comment: I want to use it as divider between two different layouts.<br>I thought about using a png but since I'm designing my app to be as resolution indipendent as possible I don't think that this is a good idea.

Comment: 9 patch image  should be your way to go, I believe.